# Convert Quark files to InDesign files

Tags: adobe-indesign, quarkxpress

Is there a quick way to convert Quark files into Indesign without having Quark?

I have InDesign CS4 and need to make changes to a Quark file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF it's a Quark 4 file, you can open it directly in InDesign.

Otherwise you can try [Q2ID](http://markzware.com/products/q2id/) from Markzware. It's pricey ($199); I've never used it, although I've heard good reports.

Beyond that, you'll have to recreate it somehow.

Comment: Just a note.. I use the Q2ID plug in... it's works very well.

Comment: Q2ID is the only game in town worth mentioning. I consider it pretty cheap, actually, considering what it does. It rocks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Convert Quark to Indesign](http://www.convertquarktoindesign.com). It's £3 a conversion. I use it it I need to convert single Quark files every now and again. Spreads to cost of buying the software as well! :)